# PHP SQLite3 Catch All Errors

Tags: php, sqlite, catch-all

I am trying ways to catch all SQLite3 errors in PHP? I have tried many and they all seem to work. Consider the code below, is it enough to catch all errors? Can someone suggest anything else?

```
$result = $stmt->execute();
if ($this->db->lastErrorCode()){
    throw new DatabaseError($this->db->lastErrorMsg(), 
                            $this->db->lastErrorCode());
} else {
    return $this->db->changes();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is actually enough because there's an error code when an error is raised of course so this must work.